# Format user input (thousands separated by ".") while typing by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking to format the input of a text field while the user is typing. Format type has to be thousand separation by "." like this:

User writes: 1000

Field must show: 1.000

I managed to put this together despite my relatively limited js knowledge, but it won't format the intended way. Unless the input number is five digits long (for example 10000 shows correctly as 10.000) it won't work. Four digit numbers are still showing without the "." seperator.

http://jsfiddle.net/zt4kjrdf/1/

Tried changing input type to number in the html as well, but to no avail.

Could somebody please guide me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

```js
$("#field-to-format").keyup(function() {
  if ($("#field-to-format").val().length == 5) {
    var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
    $("#field-to-format").val(Number(my_val).toLocaleString('da'));
  }
});
```

```css
#field-to-format {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 130px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-1">
  <div class="input">
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="text" id="field-to-format" maxlength="5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Unless the input number is five digits long it won't work` you execute the code only when the length is == 5, so obviously it won't do anything when you type 4 digits. What about changing `== 5` with `>0`?

Comment: My advise from an UX point of view, though this can be done with quite some effort in order to not totally annoy an user (e.g. her/his breaking the type flow) ... **don't** ... instead one could provide the formatting once e.g. after 1 to 2 seconds of no additional action within this field.

Comment: Thanks, but tried that aldready. Doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Peter Seliger I see where you're coming from, but this is just a backend function that will be used by me only. And with my limited js skills, i prefer to keep it as simple as possible :-).

Comment: @emilianoD85 ... _"this is just a backend function"_ ..??.. and what is then the part in the OP's question for ... _"Format user input [...]while typing"_, and all the HTML/JS?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Wordpress admin area. User = me = admin in the backend.

Comment: @emilianoD85 ... which makes it a frontend solution again ... but with you being the only user ... got it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Sorry you are right. Wrong use of words. By backend i ment admin area :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex.

```
function numberWithDots(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

The regex uses 2 lookahead assertions:

- a positive one to look for any point in the string that has a
  multiple of 3 digits in a row after it,
- a negative assertion to make sure that point only has exactly a
  multiple of 3 digits. The replacement expression puts a dot there.

Comment: This looks like an overkill to me

Comment: @todevv Thanks. My js skill is limited at this time, would you kindly show me a working example/implementation of this?

Answer (score 0):

**Complicated solution**
You could do something like this:

```
$("#field-to-format").keyup(function($("#field-to-format")) {
    return $("#field-to-format").toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

**Already implemented solutions**

Use Number.prototype.toLocaleString which is implemented in JavaScript

```
var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
console.log(my_val.toLocaleString());
```

Or if you dont want string but number you can do this:

```
var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
let new_number = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
new_number.format(my_val);
```

**Easy solution**

If you just remove the if loop (`if ($("#field-to-format").val().length == 5) {`)

in your snippet just copy paste this over your code:

```
$("#field-to-format").keyup(function() {
    var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
    $("#field-to-format").val(Number(my_val).toLocaleString('da'));
});
```

It will work for 1.000 as it is and as you wanted but then also enable larger input :D

**EDIT**

Since the author of post wanted further explanation :

First of all that is beacouse its on key up so it triggers very often thus changing 1.000 into a decimal 1,000. Secondly it doesnt go over 5 digits since you have it limited in text input so remove that then you can try either of this 2 codes (js):

```
$("#field-to-format").change(function() {
    var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
    $("#field-to-format").val(Number(my_val).toLocaleString('da'));
});


$("#field-to-format").change(function() {
    var my_val = $("#field-to-format").val();
    $("#field-to-format").val(String(my_val).replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

and in html change it to this :

```
<div class="field-1">
  <div class="input">
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="Text" id="field-to-format">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an executable code example in order to let the audience try the user experience of the chosen approach.

Comment: @BrianOrion Thanks. I tried the "Easy solution" in JSFiddle. Doesn't work for me. All formating is just gone. Could you maybe create a working example for me to see?

Comment: @emilianoD85 I edited it so that you just override your current js in the jsfiddel that you provided and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. It works with 4 digit numbers i see. But now 5 digits are broken :-(. Not showing the fifth digit, in stead just turning the "." into an ",". Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/nbj3ca0g/

Comment: @emiliano85  I gave you further explanation in the edit